# Keyword-only arguments without positional arguments

Tags: python, arguments, keyword

[image]

Kindly Explain this code that is highlighted, especially the part where the method Definition is.
Questions:

1. why Asterisk is on the Start without any parameter, What does it mean in python.
2. Asterisk before calling a function "choice", what does it mean?
3. How does it enforce python to use keyword-only arguments?

Comment: Those are two completely different uses of `*`. The first defines keyword-only parameters; the second unpacks a sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like the image explains it qzite clearly, but here is a simplified version:

`*` ends the positional arguments. In python positional args are always before keyword args.

```py
def test(a, v, b):
  print(v)

test(3, v=7, 5) # illegal, kwargs have to be last (SyntaxError) 
test(3, v=7, b=5) # legal
test(3, 7, 5) # legal
```

But lets say we want the user to always specify `v` and `b` while leaving `a` positional.

```
def test(a, *, v, b):
  print(v)

test(3, v=7, b=5) # legal
test(3, 7, 5) # illegal, takes one positional argument but 3 were given
test(3, 5, v=7, b=5) # illegal, 2 were given
```